# Why Interior Color value from constant variable returns "#000000" hex code i.e. interior color becomes black in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

When I use color number 15325914 directly it shades the cell in correct color (Light Grayish Blue).

```
Activecell.Interior.Color = 15325914
```

**Light Grayish Blue:**

[image: Light Grayish Blue]

When I use the same color number 15325914 when it is stored in a constant it shades the cell in black color (*When it is already not in the 15325914 color*).

```
Public Const LightGrayishBlue = 15325914
Activecell.Interior.Color = LightGrayishBlue
```

[image: Black Color]

Comment: you must be having some local scoped variable named after "LightGrayishBlue" and set to 0

Comment: You are not using `Option Explicit` and you have defined your `Const LightGrayishBlue` in a place where it's not accessible for the calling code, so it ends up being an undeclared variable holding `Variant/Empty` which translates to 0 which is the color black. Start with adding `Option Explicit` to the module where you are using that constant.

Comment: @Gserg OP writes that variable is declared as Public

Comment: Running a test code works properly for me with `LightGrayishBlue` declared as a `Public Const` at the module level.

Comment: @PeterT, yes, but if you also have a "Dim LightGrayishBlue As Long" in the Sub with the "Activecell.Interior.Color = LightGrayishBlue" statement, and you don't initialize it, then you'll get a black cell backgound color

Comment: @user3598756 - agreed. The OP didn't respond to your suggestion that he has such a local variable, either explicitly declared (as required by `Option Explicit`) or declared by default (by a misspelling, such as `LightGreyishBlue`). So +1 to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work when everything is setup correctly (have used similar code 1000nds of times).

The most likely reason is that `LightGrayishBlue` has the value 0 when assigned as interior color. But the black color can have several reasons:

- You have a typo in the name or the constant is not available at your code. Always use `Option Explicit` to catch such cases.
- you have a variable with the same name that "hides" the constant definition. Go to the VBA editor, move the mouse on the `LightGrayishBlue` and press Shift+F2 (*goto definition*): Does it jump to the Const definition or somewhere else? Or does it show an error "Identifier under cursor is not recognized"
- What you also can do: Set a breakpoint to the statement setting the color and check with the debugger the content of `LightGrayishBlue`. Is it 0 or does it show the expected value?
- Execute the statement (F8) that sets the color: Is the active cell now blue or black? Maybe some following code changes the color again.